# How to build Audio Visualiser from Video in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, http-live-streaming, visualizer

I'm working on a project which will have a audio playlist, Along with that i have to build a audio visualizer. I have a rough idea about how to do this if the source is an audio. The problem is, the source is a `m3u8` and i'm  using `Hls.js` with a `HTML 5` video tag to implements an HTTP Live Streaming. My goal is to build a audio player which support HTTP Live Streaming and can show visualization. What is the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope It will help

```
> let video = document.getElementById('videoId'); let audioContext = new
> AudioContext();
> 
> const UsrAg = navigator.userAgent; var stream = null; if
> (UsrAg.indexOf('Firefox') > -1) { stream = video.mozCaptureStream(); }
> else { stream = video.captureStream(); }
> 
> var audioSrc = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream) const
> analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser(); audioSrc.connect(analyser);
> analyser.fftSize = 256; const bufferLength =
> analyser.frequencyBinCount; const frequencyData = new
> Uint8Array(bufferLength);
> 
> 
> function renderFrame() {  requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
>   analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);   that.setState({
> frequencyData: frequencyData }); } renderFrame();
```